# How to design multi-level navigation menus for web and apps

Tags: navigation

We're creating some applications that need a multi-level menu navigation. This navigation menu should be presented in these environments:

1. Web (large browsers)
2. Web (responsive for devices)
3. Android app
4. iOS app
5. Possibly Windows Phone

We're stuck at deciding how to represent this navigation model across devices and platforms. Is there any best practice?

**Update:** One solution is:

Create a waterfall-like drop-down menus for web portals
Create a breadcrumb-like navigation for devices
Create a nested-accordion Android navigation drawer
For iOS, we're truly stuck.

Comment: This is a very **broad** question and the answers may tend to be **Primarily opinion based**. Those two reasons are enough to close this question. Why don't you show us some of your ideas so that we can help you with possible suggestions and edits, rather than asking the users to think from scratch. That way, we will have more clarity on this post and you'll benefit more from it too.

Comment: @VarunKN, I updated the question. This question is not broad at all. We Googled and we couldn't find a universal best practice to present navigation across devices. This is so universal, that I doubt thousands of applications have not encountered it.

Comment: Whatever your strategy is it needs to fit around the content and IA for your audience in the context of different device usage use cases. On the off chance that your content and IA is very organic, and that your users have the same requirements across all devices, you would have a very big job in design and testing as part of your product lifecycle.

Comment: I have search a long time for the "best" navigation for all devices. For now this is the best solution (work in progress): http://94.237.92.101:6060

Answer (score 3):

You can always try the [**MultiLevel Push Menu**](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html) which works fine for all the devices you mention and has very clear and easy to follow hierarchies.

[image]

Additionally, you could also use [**Responsive Multilevel Menu**](http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/) which is more or less the same, only that not taking the whole vertical space

[image]

Comment: Super amazing. It's super amazing. I just can't say it enough, it's super amazing. Yet it has one drawback. Going from one leaf, to another leaf means traversing into the root (or common ancestor), and then going back to the other leaf. Is this really a drawback?

Comment: I don't think so, to me it gives reference to the user, but as in anything UX, you'll need to test it and see

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of IOS menu design : 
Hope it will help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- consider the acceptable level of [information density](https://simplicable.com/new/information-density) for your target audience(s). Basically too many navigation levels on the same page are useful for those who are going to visit the same interface over and over again. That is people, who would have the time to learn it anyway and after that would need to have everything immediately reachable on the same page. If you expect users to come and go, then you'd better invest in navigation consisting in more but easier steps (e.g. many pages of [progressive disclosure](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/progressive-disclosure));
- keep navigation on the left, based on this hypothesis: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/any-research-on-right-hand-left-hand-based-preferences-when-interacting-with-an