# How to manage many level navigation before the main operation

Tags: usability, information-architecture, structure, efficiency

I am designing web application which needs 4 levels to manage the flow charts which is the main purpose of the application .
The structure is something like this:

> Company names - folder
>
> > Component names - sub-folder
> >
> > > Group name - sub - sub - folder
> > >
> > > > List of flow charts

The problem is the user has to make 4 clicks to reach its main task how should the levels be grouped or restructured to make the process efficient

Comment: Similar to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/how-to-design-multi-level-navigation-menus-for-web-and-apps

Comment: Can you share more context? What is exactly the workflow and starting point for the user? Why do they (want to) use it this way? How many companies, components, groups and lists are there? Without details it is hard to give a decent answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Mega Menus](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/).

Maybe also some kind of "Favorites" or "Recents" on the landing page could help to bring the users to their last task more quickly.

[image: Mega menu]

Answer (score 1):

Use dropdown menus with an autocomplete-enabled text search, and only show the next selection level of the previous has been selected.

---

Company: `▼ ACME inc`
Component: `▼ Foobar`
Group: `▼ Bazgroup`

---

Offer the option to bookmark selections (maybe even incomplete selections like 
`folder` `subfolder` `___`).

Usually I would advise against dropdowns, but in combination with a text search with suggestions/autocomplete, this solution would provide the users with an easy way to make their selections. New users can skim the (alphabetically sorted?) dropdowns for their target choice, tenured users can use their bookmarks or just type the first couple of letters of the item they want.

Hint: there are multiple ways to make suggestions, I personally think that sublime text does a great job with this.

Comment: This also has the benefit of not flooding the user with options, but have them take one decision step at a time, reducing mental workload. If you make clear that the selection process is segmented, you also avoid frustration or confusion of users who are e.g not aware of other companies and are just looking for a certain component.